# Syslog-ng connecting to mysql

Tags: mysql, syslog-ng

I would like to log files from a switch to a mysql database. I am using syslog-ng  and in the configuration file, i have done the following amendments

```
filter f_no_debug { not level(debug); };

destination d_mysql {
sql(
type(mysql)
username("logs")
password("SECUREPASSWORD")
database("logs")
host("localhost")
table("logs")
columns("host", "facility", "priority", "level", "tag", "datetime", "program", "msg")
values("$HOST", "$FACILITY", "$PRIORITY", "$LEVEL", "$TAG","$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY $HOUR:$MIN:$SEC","$PROGRAM", "$MSG")
indexes("datetime", "host", "program", "pid", "message")
);
};

log {source(s_net); source(s_src); filter(f_no_debug); destination(d_mysql); }
```

When i run the command `service syslog restart`, i get the following error

> Unable to initialize database access (DBI);rc='-1', error='No such
>   file or directory (2)' Error initializing dest
>   driver;dest='d_mysql',id='d_mysql'#0 Error initializing message
>   pipeline

How can i overcome this problem to enable logs to be directed to the database?

Answer (score 8):

On `Ubuntu` and `Debian`:

MySQL database server driver for libdbi:

```
apt-get install libdbd-mysql
```

PostgreSQL database server driver for libdbi:

```
apt-get install libdbd-pgsql
```

SQLite3 database driver for libdbi:

```
apt-get install libdbd-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 3):

This message seems to be caused when the libdbi drivers are not installed. Take a look at http://libdbi.sourceforge.net/ or see if there is a libdbi package for your distribution.